# MySql get two values from an id

Tags: php, mysql

I have this sql query below, notice the field `receiver` that returns on id from `table_1`

My question is how would I get the receivers `FirstName` and `LastName` in the `receiver` spot?

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    FirstName, 
    LastName, 
    table_2.status, 
    (select FirstName, LastName from table_1 where table_1.id = table_2.receiver) as receiver 
FROM table_1
INNER JOIN 
    table_2 on table_1.key_2 = CONCAT('OFFLINE-', table_2.id)
ORDER BY FirstName, LastName
```

I added a subquery to my SQL, but this gives me a syntax error :(

Comment: where is receiver data stored, which table? Can you add sample data from both  tables and expected results?

Comment: What do you mean by "the receiver spot"? You want to change the order of the output columns?

Comment: the receiver data is stored in table_1

Comment: Example each data row has an id and a receiver, the receiver is the id of someone else in table_1. I am looking to get the recivers first and last name.

Answer (score 1):

```
select distinct FirstName, LastName, table_2.status, CONCAT(FirstName, ' ', LastName) 
from table_1 inner join table_2 on table_1.key_2 = CONCAT('OFFLINE-', table_2.id) 
order by FirstName, LastName
```

Answer (score 0):

This works :)

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    FirstName, 
    LastName, 
    table_2.status, 
    (select CONCAT(FirstName,' ',LastName) as Name from table_1 where id=receiver) as receiver, 
FROM table_1
INNER JOIN 
    table_2 on table_1.key_2 = CONCAT('OFFLINE-', table_2.id)
ORDER BY FirstName, LastName
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do it with aliases instead of a subquery:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    t2.FirstName, 
    t2.LastName, 
    t2.status, 
    CONCAT(t1.FirstName,' ', t1.LastName) as receiver
FROM table_1 t1
INNER JOIN 
    table_2 t2 on t1.key_2 = CONCAT('OFFLINE-', t2.id)
ORDER BY t1.FirstName, t1.LastName
```